# Chrome API is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a Chrome extension that interacts with Dropbox's API, using OAuth2. I have read the Identity API documentation but I am confused on where to invoke `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()`.

I have created a background page, and included a .js script which calls `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()`, but I get `undefined` when I call `console.log(chrome.identity)`. `console.log(chrome)` prints an object to console.

Am I misunderstanding something? Do I have to use a listener and invoke that function after something happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if `chrome.something` is undefined while it should exist, you don't have permissions to use it. Either you need a permission in your manifest, or it cannot be used in the current context (i.e. a content script).

In your case, you must be missing `"identity"` permission in the manifest. It's specified in the documentation header.

Comment: Yep I was waiting for stackoverflow to let me lol. they have a time restriction