# How to access chrome.bookmarks in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have read google's [developer chrome.bookmarks doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) and googled it, still can't  find a way to access `chrome.bookmarks` in **Chrome Console**.

But I do can access `chrome` in Chrome Console

```
console.log(chrome) //run this in Chrome Console
// Object {app: Object, webstore: Object, runtime: Object, loadTimes: function, csi: function}
```

But try access `chrome.bookmarks` the same way, returned print `undefined`

```
console.log(chrome.bookmarks)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Include the manifest in your question.

Comment: Are you looking at the console in a page with a `chrome-extension://...` URL? Does your extension have the `bookmarks` permission?

Comment: @Josh Lee  Sorry, I didn't make it clear, I have edited the question again. I mean access chrome.bookmarks in Chrome Console, not in a chrome extension.

Comment: Yes, the documentation you linked to makes clear that this is an API for chrome extensions to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome API is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437648/chrome-api-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple [consoles for your extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011).  To access `chrome.bookmarks` from the console, you will need to be using a DevTools which is associated with a page in the background context (e.g. the background page, or popup, etc.). You will also need to have declared the [`bookmarks` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#bookmarks) in your *manifest.json*.

Example of accessing `chrome.bookmarks` from the background page's DevTools:

[image: Example of accessing <code>chrome.bookmarks</code>]